# How to separate items in Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])

>>> data
array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

I want to separate items in *data*. Desired output:

```
>>> data
array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
```

Comment: `data.reshape(-1,1)`?

Comment: The first `data` is (1,4) shape. The second (4,1).  You need some more practice looking at and changing the `shape` of arrays.

Comment: Also look at `data.ravel()`, the 1d (4,) equivalent array.